# What is the 'const' keyword in Swift?

Tags: swift, keyword

I was reading [this](https://news.realm.io/news/tryswift-yasuhiro-inami-parser-combinator/) article and I came across the following two functions:

```
// Sequence actions, discarding the value of the second argument
func <* <A, B>(p: Parser<A>, q: Parser<B>) -> Parser<A> {
    return const <^> p <*> q
}

// Sequence actions, discarding the value of the first argument
func *> <A, B>(p: Parser<A>, q: Parser<B>) -> Parser<B> {
    return const(id) <^> p <*> q
}
```

What are the `const` and `const(id)`? I'm guessing they are some kind of values, but what values? Are they implicit left- or right-hand side operands? (This is just a shot in the dark). I could not find any info about it.

Comment: I believe these are functions in his parser, not part of Foundation.

Comment: @Rob ah that would make sense!

Comment: https://github.com/tryswift/TryParsec/blob/4dc2cadc23311fc27dbcbd108727bab46905e229/Sources/TryParsec/Prelude.swift#L7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has no `const` keyword.

The talk uses [the TryParsec library](https://github.com/tryswift/TryParsec), which defines [this `const` function](https://github.com/tryswift/TryParsec/blob/4dc2cadc23311fc27dbcbd108727bab46905e229/Sources/TryParsec/Prelude.swift#L8):

```
/// Constant function.
internal func const<A, B>(_ a: A) -> (B) -> A
{
    return { _ in a }
}
```